# FullPage.js and SlimScrolling.js change scroll steps

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fullpage.js, slimscroll

I have implemented FullPage.js with overflowScroll:true, as I read needs slimscroll.js. everything works fine apart of the issue that the scroll inside a section kinda jumps too much, is there a way to make the scroll step less?

NOTE: for some reason it doesn't let me add a function from slimscroll with the step.
any ideas?

also they said that FullPage.js already made a version with iScroll but seems that I can't find it anywhere.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

As I answered in your comment on [the article](http://alvarotrigo.com/blog/fullpage-jquery-plugin-for-fullscreen-scrolling-websites/).

> fullPage.js is not using slimScroll.js anymore but iScroll.js instead. You might be able to find something about that in their docs http://iscrolljs.com/. Then you can ass the options to fullPage.js through the option `scrollOverflowOptions` as detailed in the docs.

For example:

```
$('#fullPage').fullPage({
    scrollOverflowOptions:{
        demo: 'aaa'
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi there, following this article https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js the overflowscroll.js supposed to be on iScroll if I am not wrong, but when I am trying to implement it it says that slimScroll.js is not a function, which means that is still searching form slimscroll, how can I make it work?

Comment: Make sure you use the latest fullPage.js verison 2.9.2.